# Convert Struct to a Map using Reflect

Tags: go

I have a peace of code that converting struct to a map, but not all of the tests are passing.
I'm struggling with that test **req.Equal(simple, res["simple"])**.

I need to "res[simple]" return "{Name:Superman ID:3388}", but it returns "map[id:3388 name:Superman]"

```
                Error:          Not equal:
                                expected: convertor.SimpleStruct(convertor.SimpleStruct{Name:"Superman", ID:3388})
                                actual  : map[string]interface {}(map[string]interface {}{"id":3388, "name":"Superman"})
```

```
func StructToMap(item interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    res := map[string]interface{}{}
    v := reflect.TypeOf(item)
    reflectValue := reflect.ValueOf(item)
    reflectValue = reflect.Indirect(reflectValue)

    if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = v.Elem()
    }
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        tag := v.Field(i).Tag.Get("keyname")
        field := reflectValue.Field(i).Interface()
        if tag == "" {
            tag = v.Field(i).Tag.Get(v.Name())
        }
        if tag != "" && tag != "-" {
            if v.Field(i).Type.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                res[tag] = StructToMap(field)
            } else {
                res[tag] = field
            }
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Here is my tests:

```
func TestStructToMap(t *testing.T) {
    req := require.New(t)
    simple := SimpleStruct{
        Name: "Superman",
        ID:   3388,
    }
    withStructFiled := StructWithStructField{
        Simple:  simple,
        Message: "message",
    }
    t.Run("simple test", func(t *testing.T) {
        req.Equal(simple.Name, res["name"])
        req.Equal(simple.ID, res["id"])
    })
    t.Run("with struct field", func(t *testing.T) {
        req.Equal(simple, res["simple"])

    })
}
```

Comment: maybe want to use this package https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure

Comment: You say you are converting a struct to a map. The test result seems to confirm that. Why do you want the output *not* to be a map? Why do you want the output to be a struct? Are you trying to convert a struct to a struct?

Comment: @mkopriva no, the tests just testing various types of structs that i convert. In this case a struct has a field of struct.

Comment: In `req.Equal(simple, res["simple"])` the `simple` variable is of type `SimpleStruct` which is, I assume, of kind `struct`. Question for you: do you want `res["simple"]` to be of type `SimpleStruct` and kind `struct`? Or do you want `res["simple"]` be of type `map[string]interface{}`? Should `StructToMap` convert a struct recursively? Or should it not?

Comment: @mkopriva i want **res["simple"]**  to be of type **SimpleStruct**. It should not convert a struct recursively. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: If you don't want to convert recursively then you should remove the recursive part of the `StructToMap` code. I.e. remove `if v.Field(i).Type.Kind() == reflect.Struct { res[tag] = StructToMap(field) }`. Right?

Comment: @mkopriva yes, you are right, thanks, i missed that moment =)